# AWS / Python Lambda function checking if a query string is present

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Within my lambda function, which takes in event api query strings, I want to check if one is present. The below works if it is:

```
if event['queryStringParameters']['order'] == 'desc':
        file_names.append('hello')
```

I have tried `event['queryStringParameters']['order'] != null`  but if there is no order query string used the lambda function the function breaks causing a 502 response. How do I check if a query string is not used without it breaking?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Always check if the dict contains an key before referencing it.

```
if 'queryStringParameters' in event and 'order' in event['queryStringParameters']:
```

Comment: fantastic! That's it :)

Answer (score 3):

I successfully use the dictionary.get method as in:

```
event['queryStringParameters'].get('param1')
```

or with a default value:

```
event['queryStringParameters'].get('param1', '')
```

Check out the syntax: https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_get.asp